# How can I create an IIS 7 module interface?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have had many requests come in to a project that I work on, to include an IIS 7 module interface.

Does anybody know of any resources for creating an IIS 7.0 module interface?

I have searched http://www.iis.net and I have not really found a good article on the basics of how to create an IIS 7.0 module interface.

It can be for any programing article on how to create a module interface for IIS 7.0 (Windows 2008) or IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2).

I found a couple sources, has anybody found anything that is better or more descriptive on the programming side?

- [Modules Overview](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/)

Comment: Tags are not an appropriate place for content. Use discretion in creating new tags to aid users in finding relevant data.

Comment: iis 7.5 and windows2008r2 are definitely appropriate.  They are related to the question

Comment: So what exactly is your problem with module-interface that does occur in the content?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect set of tags to me. :)

Comment: It is quite appropriate to place information such as "IIS 7.5" and Windows2008 r2 in the content of the question.  Creating new tags, however, seems likely to lead to confusion.

Comment: a) Your tags make no sense to the content and are just an attempt to add additional content to your question. They wont help anything and have never been used before.

Comment: b) I fail to find anything under google for module interface that is relevant. Provide a link and I would reconsider.

Comment: c) You are also rolling back edits that fix your question itself.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed. There is a concerted effort underway to merge these kinds of useless tags to increase signal and lessen noise.

Comment: Really a whole version change from 7.0 and 7.5 is considered useless tags?  Maybe we should consider Windows95 and WindowsVista the same thing?

Comment: Actually no it isn't this has been fought many times over, and it has always been decided that if it is not SPAM and it is part of the question it is valid.

Comment: This is ridiculous.  Serial editors should get a rep hit.  Demerits all around!

Comment: @RichB so only questions are acceptable if you have given your stamp of approval?  How is that in anyway a community effort?

Comment: I think the link provides context for his question

Comment: @recursive: Taking offensive and spam content out of a question is a civic duty here. The real problem is when OPs decide to continue to troll. This is an ongoing issue with this user and has been reported to uservoice.

Comment: @RichB actually you do, because there are many different kinds of modules, and it helps the answer to know and help me decide which type is best.

Comment: @RichB it gives context to the question, there exisits a world outside of StackOverflow

Comment: @RichB but it is relavent to the question, plus what am I gaining, it is already popular, has 1000 downloads in the past month, and doesn't give me any ad money.

Comment: By the way I see your comment was deleted, but I didn't do it. So don't blame me this time.

Comment: 31 revisions and 19 comments in one hour.  what the hell is wrong with you.

Comment: I am going to love to see what the reasoning behind this close is, it should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help to get started:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/#Getting
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/globalModules

Comment: Anything i can do to help and get you closer to an answer is my goal.

Comment: This was very useful, I don't know if you saw my last comment, it was deleted pretty quickly, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to "Step 3 - Creating the Image Copyright UI Module" of this article:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/168/an-end-to-end-extensibility-example-for-iis-70-developers/

It provides a step-by-step on creating a GUI for configuring a custom IIS 7 module.